# How to bypass the Company mandatory field on a Lead

Tags: lead-conversion

We have a form in Form Assembly that includes a Yes/No question. If users click 'Yes', they're asked to give the name of a company but if they say 'No', they won't see those fields and therefore won't fill in a company name as it's not relevant to them.
The company field on the form is mapped with the company field on the Campaign member. A lead is created when it is not an existing contact.

For those who don't fill in the company name on the form, Form Assembly shows the error "Create Lead - Required fields are missing: [Company]" as the Company field is required on a lead.

Is there a way to bypass this issue by pre-populating the lead's company field with something like 'Not provided' or 'N/A' when there is no company info? Or any simpler solutions?

Is it a valid option to use Form Assembly's Skif-if formulas? https://help.formassembly.com/help/340548-formulas-for-common-uses#skip-if-formulas

Comment: I don't think Skip-if Formula is the right tool to use because you always want to trigger the creation of a lead in Salesforce even if the company field is blank on the Form Assembly's form. Is it possible to set a default value for the Company field in Form Assembly and if the user gets to the "Yes" path, it will use the value from his input?

Comment: Common solution is to either send some default company name or pre-fill it on SF side via a trigger/flow/etc.